# if model has a certain value then count

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

My `Model.PendingActivation` (`int?`) can be `0`, `1` or `Null`. `1` is pending, I want to count how many `1`s there are and display that count in my view?

```
@if (Model.PendingActivation.HasValue == "1")
{
  <a>@Html.Encode(Model.PendingActivation.Count)</a>
}
```

Not sure how I can count how many are pending.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Have you even tried it?

Comment: `int` does not have a `Count` property. Not clear what your trying to do. Do you want to count all items in a collection that have `PendingActivation == 1`?

Comment: `HasValue` means that int? is not null

Comment: So, @KirstyWhite. What is the data type of `Model`?

Comment: How about `Model.PendingActivation.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 1`?

Comment: As per above explained, Model.PendingActivation is a property so it give  only 0-Done or 1-Pending or null-N/A. There is no clue that it is a list. Please give more sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Model` is a list of some type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can `Count()` them:

```
<a>@Html.Encode(Model.Count(m => m.PendingActivation != null && m.PendingActivation.HasValue && m.PendingActivation.Value == 1))</a>
```

The code between `Count()` is the expression that checks every item in the list, in this case you want to have `PendingActivation == 1`, which this expression checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<a>@Html.Encode(Model.FindAll(m => m.PendingActivation == 1).Count()</a>
```